# EmojiAppCompatTextView with an ellipsis and an emoji afterwards not working properly

Tags: android, textview, emoji

I have an EmojiAppCompatTextView with the maxLines set to 2 and ellipsis set to end, but if there is an emoji after where the ellipsis is, it still puts the emoji after the ellipsis and makes the text get cut off on the sides because there isnt enough space for the emoji.

Seems like an inherent bug in EmojiAppCompatTextView but maybe there is a way to fix it...

how it should look (emoji before the ellipsis works fine):

[image: emoji before ellipsis]

how it actually looks

[image: emoji after ellipsis]

any ideas?

the textviews xml for good measure:

```
<android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        app:fontPath="fonts/Lato-LightItalic.ttf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="13sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite an old issue, but this may help someone who might at up here as I did :)

While initialing your layout put this:

```
tv_message?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener { fixEmojiAfterEllipses() }
```

and to fix it after layout phrase:

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private fun fixEmojiAfterEllipses() {
    tv_message?.let {
        val count = it.layout?.getEllipsisCount(0) ?: 0
        if (count > 0) {
            it.text = "${it.text.substring(0, it.text.length - count)}..."
        }
    }
}
```

This might give you some idea how to fix it in your case... Just don;t forget to change argument to getEllipsesCount.